# using vba to select a list box item

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

My issue is being able to select the row in a list box using vba.
My program loops through a table and finds the value for the listbox ie an integer/row number and sets it in a variable likewise for the listbox name.

So listbox name = variable LstName
ListBox value = strvalue as integer.

I want to then select that row in the listbox so it is highlighted 
I just cannot get it to work. If I use actual names and nemeric value it works perfectly but combining `me.LstName.selected(strValue) = True` creates an error

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the error is? - thanks :)

Comment: @Ian H Was wondering if you got  a solution for your problem. I have got similar problem as this and am looking for answers.

Answer (score 4):

That's not how list boxes work. `LstName.Selected(iRow as Long) As Long` only takes numbers, and returns -1 for true, 0 for false.

If you want to set an item on a listbox based on a string, you can use the following:

```vb
Public Sub ListboxSelectString(lstListbox As ListBox, strToSelect As String, Optional SelectDeselect As Boolean = True)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To lstListbox.ListCount - 1
        If lstListbox.ItemData(i) = strToSelect Then
            lstListbox.Selected(i) = SelectDeselect
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Then you can use `ListboxSelectString Me.LstName, strValue` to select `strValue` on `Me.LstName`

Comment: hi thanks for that I shall give a go asap and hpfully all will be well.....

Comment: hi im a little unclear with this so sorry... I already have the number of the row I want to choose in the listbox I just want to select that item from the number.My code is to cycle through a form and write the controls to a temp table then insert the control value into the table. Following that I may leave the form using a command button..... when im finished I want to return to the form and write back the values from the temp table. Some controls are listBoxes which I have the number 0 to n.... The issue I have is how to select that record in the list again. Thanks

Comment: Then please provide a full description (what the values of your listbox are (`ListCount`), what the value and type of your `strValue` is, the error number and description you encounter, etc..